# Git: Determine number of commits pulled down after doing git pull?

Tags: git

How can you determine the number of commits pulled down after doing `git pull`?

When we do `git pull` I see output such as:

```
9 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 39 deletions(-)
```

But I can't determine how many commits were pulled down like you can with `hg fetch`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `git pull`, you can do a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. *Before* you do the merge, a `git status` will show you how many commits "behind" you are; that is the number of commits you have fetched, assuming you were 0 behind before the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

Or

```
git shortlog | grep -E '^[ ]+\w+' | wc -l
```

Kindly let me know if these commands helped

Answer (score 0):

if, like me, you had already performed the pull, the (good) advice of
`git status` after a `git fetch` can't help you.

this seems to work:

```
$ git reflog
e5545c33c (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: rebase (finish): returning to refs/heads/main
e5545c33c (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: rebase (start): checkout refs/remotes/origin/main
5400c9c85 HEAD@{2}: commit: <redacted>
<... snipped ...>

# we see ^ that my pull performed a rebase. I prefer rebase over merge and am
# not sure how merge would behave in this situation - sorry.

# next, we grab the commit below the rebase:
$ REF=5400c9c85

# count commits between that and HEAD
$ git rev-list --count $REF..
8
```